# How do I change a float number into an array so that I can concatenate it with a zeros function in Python?

Tags: python, concatenation

I am extremely new to Python and I have tried searching for answers and debugging for days but I could not solve this issue. Please help me.

#### Main Question: How do I concatenate a zeros function, zeros((1,142)) with a float number, 1954.0 ?

Things I have tried:

1. Converting the float number, 1954.0 into an array using: `numpy.array(1954.0)`
2. Concatenate the zeros function with the converted float number: `concatenate((zeros(1,142), numpy.array(1954.0)))`

   > [It gave a ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions]
3. I tried doing this instead: `concatenate((zeros(1,142)), numpy.array([[1954.0]])))` and it gave a DIFFERENT ValueError message.

   > [ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly]
4. I have checked using: `type(numpy.array(1954.0))` and it says `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and also checked using: `type((zeros(1,142))` and it says `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Both are of the same type, which means I should be able to concatenate but somehow it still gives me the various error messages shown in point 2 and 3.

I am desperately in need of help for this.

Answer (score 0):

Nicer ways to accomplish this are

```
a = numpy.zeros((1,143))
a[0, -1] = 1954
```

or

```
a = numpy.append(numpy.zeros((1,142)), 1954)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike Graham's answer's are nicer but if you insist on using concatenate, then the following will work:

```
x = np.zeros( (1,143))
y = np.array([[1943]])
tot = np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried that in point 3 and got the error message: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly